# Looking for a textbook that covers rotational collisions in depth

Tags: rotational-dynamics, resource-recommendations, collision

I am looking for a textbook that covers rotational collisions. I’m looking to understand “ball-off-wall” collisions. Topics might include reflection, the effects of spin on the ball, and treatment of slippage and friction.

A couple of examples.

- First, here’s a [Wired article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjArZPtkK2BAxXJl2oFHRsGCKYQFnoECBYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wired.com%2F2016%2F05%2Fswear-theres-reason-model-ball-bouncing-off-wall%2F&usg=AOvVaw1SuaIYdqNGm7ejUCxRbblv&opi=89978449) about the “law of reflection” for ball-wall collisions.
- A second example is this exercise I found [Physics Forums](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/a-spinning-ball-hits-a-wall-and-bounces-back-question.114250/). I would like the book to have similar exercises:

> A solid ball with mass M, radius R, speed U0, angular speed W0 hits a wall at the angle theta0. after the hit, the ball goes away with an angle theta1, angular speed W1 and speed U1. i'm asked to find the angular momentum for the point of hit, before and after the hit. i'm also asked to find the neccesary conditions of U0, W0, and theta0 so that the path of the ball after the hit would be 90 degrees from the wall.

- This question: [Rolling ball hits the wall](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/423460/rolling-ball-hits-the-wall).

Perhaps I’ve missed it, but I looked closely at the chapters and exercises on rotation in the 13th edition of University Physics (Young and Freedman) and did not find any coverage.

Online the closest I’ve found in section 10.6 in the [Physics LibreText](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/College_Physics/College_Physics_1e_(OpenStax)/10%3A_Rotational_Motion_and_Angular_Momentum/10.06%3A_Collisions_of_Extended_Bodies_in_Two_Dimensions), but that mostly discusses rotation after a collision.

Lastly, “rotational collision” may not be the correct term, which is why I’m having trouble finding resources.

Comment: You can't expect to have a book on every special case in mechanics, mostly you have to learn the basics like law of conservation of angular momentum, of momentum, of energy.

Comment: A more likely source would be the [American Journal of Physics](https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/ajp), which publishes quite a lot of articles that can be classified as "interesting and detailed extensions of undergraduate mechanics problems", like what you're asking here.  You might try trawling through their archives.